# Ajax загрузка + первью

Tags: ajax

Нужно реализовать загрузку <input type="file"> картинки и чтобы она отобразилась ниже (под кнопкой) без перезагрузки станицы.
Знаю что делается через ajax но с ним не сталкивался.
Посоветуйте плагин какой нибудь?
Нагуглить не могу что-либо подходящее.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://github.com/valums/file-uploader
```

нужен для загрузки файла без перезагрузки. Далее по `Success`'у вставить картинку внизу с помощью `jQuery`.